# get referral value after installing app from playstore

Tags: android, deep-linking, google-analytics-campaign-builder

I am implementing deep linking by a url

http://www.skillshaatapp.com/v1/apk?playstore=true&mobile=8896203990

if app is install in my device its working fine. I received mobile.

but,

If app is not install my deep link redirect to play store by link

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mlai.android.skillshaat&url=http://skillshaatapp.com&mobile=8896203990

in this case i do not receive mobile.

Please give me solution how we receive parameter passed in playstore link.

I listen about CampaignTrackingReceiver but no idea how to implement it.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `InstallReferrerReceiver` (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/InstallReferrerReceiver)

For example to get `referrer` info

```
public class InstallReferrerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        String referrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");
        Ln.i("InstallReferrerReceiver.onReceive() - referrer = " + referrer);

    }
}
```

having added following to `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <receiver android:name="<your package>.InstallReferrerReceiver" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: @Rajnish Kumar Chaubey did you get chance to try this?